Do conclusions from auction theory persist when embedded into a zero-sum game?
Two interesting conclusions from auction theory are...

In an open-price ascending-bid auction, the winner bids (up to the
increment) the second highest valuation.
In a dollar auction, each player may bid over their valuation by
an arbitrary amount if they keep expecting the auction to end soon
enough, but there is a mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium based on the
increment which ends the game eventually (Wikipedia says there are
also pure strategy Nash Equilibria, but I'm not sure what those are).

I want to know what happens if either of these auctions are embedded into a zero-sum game.
In Monopoly for example, players bid in open-price ascending-bid auctions for properties.  If this example is trivial because all information in Monopoly is/has-been public and thus the players' valuations should be equal, then consider modified Monopoly in which each player has (and knows the contents of) personal Chance and Community Chest decks, so that valuations are based on expectations over different information sets and may rationally differ.  Especially in the two-player case (what I'm most interested in), there may be incentive for the player with the second highest valuation to bid higher because in the zero-sum context (unlike the original) they want to reduce their opponent's expected profit, and this may in turn affect how the player with the highest valuation bids, and so forth.  What quantity should the winner actually bid?
Similarly if we changed the rules so that each player pays as they bid, win or lose (the dollar auction), would the qualitative conclusion from the non-zero-sum context still hold, such that players may rationally bid over their valuation yet a mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium may end the bidding before someone bids all of their capital?
